# How to extend an OSM or raster area in Qgis (into 'No Data' area)?

Tags: openstreetmap, raster, shapefile, qgis

I need to do the opposite of clipping down a raster in Qgis (or Gdal, Python etc - even R if someone can provide the script).

I have a dataset from Open StreetMap (*.OSM) which includes the south west corner of a country. I have also converted this to a SHP file or Raster format).

To match with my other Maxent datasets I need to expand the OSM data south and west so I am only increasing the 'no data' areas at the left and bottom of the files.

Is there a way to do this in Qgis?

Comment: Offtopic for stackoverflow, re-ask your question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @scai - moved to gis.stackexchange.com although a Python or R solution would have been fine.

Comment: The people at gis.stackexchange.com also know Python and R :). New question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198611/how-to-extend-an-osm-or-raster-area-in-qgis-into-no-data-area

Answer (score 0):

This process worked for me:

http://ssrebelious.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/raster-extent-modification-using-qgis.html

"In QGIS you can change extent of the rasters. Lets examine one of the worst case scenarios. There are two overlapping (one band) rasters A and B. Say, we need to add A values to B values and get the final image to have extent that will contain both images."